# Spring WebFlux WebClient: receive part of response

Tags: java, webclient, spring-webflux

I use WebClient (spring webflux) to send some information and do not really care about response, just log it.  If it is huge, I do not need to read everything, but only 500 bytes or so. As I understand bodyToMono() read whole body into memory. How to get only a beginning of a body?

```
client.post()
   .syncBody(payload)
   .retrieve()
   .bodyToMono(String.class)
   .subscribe( r -> logResponce(r),
               t -> logException(t));
```

Comment: Would you like to execute kinda "partial" read of your response? Or you would like to read the whole response and just decrease amount of logged symbols?

Comment: I need partial read. (just in case if somebody sends me 1Gb respond)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best that I was able to come with:

```
    WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://www.example.com/");
    client.post()
       .syncBody("test")
       .exchange()
       .flatMap(response->response.body((t,m)->t.getBody().next()))
       .subscribe( r -> {
              System.out.println("Available bytes:" + r.readableByteCount());
              final int limit = r.readableByteCount() < 500 ? r.readableByteCount() : 500;
              System.out.println("Limit:" + limit);
              byte[] dst = new byte[limit];
              r.asByteBuffer().get(dst, 0, limit);
              System.out.println("body=" + new String(dst, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
          },
          t -> System.out.println(t));
```

It consumes first block of data and prints first 500 characters.

Comment: as I said I need a beginnig of response, I want to log it.

Comment: right, I missed the point. I think you need to use 'exchange' method and custom BodyExtractor.

Comment: I feel that it is exactly what I need. But what about all this warnings (org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientResponse): "you must always use one of the body or toEntity methods to ensure resources are released and avoid potential issues with HTTP connection pooling"
I can't see something like that in you suggestion.

Comment: It uses response.body method with a lambda as body extractor. t is ReactiveHttpInputMessage, t.getBody() returns Flux<DataBuffer> (which is a flow of raw data bytes). t.getBody().next() gets the first DataBuffer and returns a Mono<DataBuffer> for the first block and skip the rest. subscribe extracts first 500 bytes from the response, convert into String in UTF_8 and prints it. So, in a sense, we used all the body (the rest is skipped by the 'next' method).

Comment: r.asByteBuffer().get(dst, 0, 500); - if the response is shorter than 500, we get exception here

Comment: I corrected the code to take available bytes into account

Comment: Is it better to use map() after .flatMap() to transfer cutting logic form subscribe to map(), what do you think?

Comment: I don't' think so. In case of an error, map operation will be useless. Formatting and printing should be the final operation.

Comment: One think is confusing: readableByteCount() - how possible to know that number without reading whole body?

Comment: Let's change 1 row to System.out.println("body="+new String(dst, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
In case of empty body response I can't see body=

Comment: @PavelMolchanov How to get all items? (iterate all, not only the first)